# Emulate Ubuntu on a "slow" machine

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

How would I be able to emulate Ubuntu running on a machine of a certain technical specification? I have decided to run Ubuntu in a virtual machine. In VirtualBox, I can limit the amount of RAM the virtual machine can get but I cannot limit the amount of CPU. Without physically trying the software on a computer, how would I be able to emulate the physical specifications of the system, such as CPU, network and a 5400RPM hard disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can, go to the settings of the VM, system tab, processor sub-tab and theres the settings you're looking for.